# Laravel 4 form post issue

Tags: php, forms, post, laravel

my problem is that when i submit my form it pass through the get method.
The workflow is form submit -> get -> post and it should be form submit -> post.
I need to have a condition in my get method to validate de array is not null

My code:
**Routes**

```
    Route::get('/pre-register-birth',array('as'=>'pre-register-birth', 'uses'=>'UserController@preRegisterBirthData'));
    Route::post('/pre-register-birth', 'UserController@preRegisterBirthDataPost');
```

**View**

```
    {{ Form::open(array('method' => 'POST', 'action' =>  'UserController@preRegisterBirthDataPost',
        'class'=>'form-horizontal', 'id'=>'regist-form')) }}
```

**Controller**

```
    public function preRegisterBirthData()
{
    $user = Session::get('user');

    if ($user)
        return View::make('user/pre-register-birth')->with('tempUser', $user);
    else
        return Redirect::Route('pre-register-get');
}

public function preRegisterBirthDataPost()
{
    $validator = Validator::make(Input::all(),
        array(
            'birthplace' => 'required|max:100',
            'birthdate' => 'required|max:100|date|date_format:Y-m-d'
        )
    );
    if ($validator->fails()) {
        return Redirect::Route('pre-register-birth')
            ->withErrors($validator)
            ->withInput();
    } else {
        $user = array(
            'email' => Input::get('email'),
            'pass' => Input::get('pass'),
            'name' => Input::get('name'),
            'surname' => Input::get('surname'),
            'birthplace' => Input::get('birthplace'),
            'birthdate' => Input::get('birthdate'),
            'hourKnow' => Input::get('hourKnow'),
            'dataCorrect' => Input::get('dataCorrect'),
            'news' => Input::get('news'),
        );
        return Redirect::Route('pre-register-terms')->with('user', $user);
    }
}
```

Comment: Please can you add your generated HTML too? (The HTML when you view source in the browser)

Comment: Change your `action` in the form to `/pre-register-birth` Laravel will work out its a post request, look at your routes and therefore send it to your desired controller method. Is there any reason you're not using the standard Laravel controller methods and set up?

Comment: your solution doesn't work, what do you mean with standard Laravel controller methods and set up.

Comment: well normally your route is related to your controller method, and your method is related to your HTTP request method. For example, `getIndex` and `postIndex` on the `UserController` will have a route of `/user`. Have you watched any of the [Laracast videos](https://laracasts.com/)? Might be useful.

Answer (score 0):

I think I've seen this issue before. Laravel for whatever odd reason doesn't like the `action => ...` So, change your form declaration from a to b:

```
// A
{{ Form::open(array('method' => 'POST', 'action' =>  'UserController@preRegisterBirthDataPost',
    'class'=>'form-horizontal', 'id'=>'regist-form')) }}

// B
{{ Form::open(array('method' => 'POST', 'url' =>  'pre-register-birth',
    'class'=>'form-horizontal', 'id'=>'regist-form')) }}
```

Notice I changed `action => ...` to `url => ...` It's a small change, but it might solve it. However, you may need to add in:

```
Route::post('/pre-register-birth', array('as'=> 'pre-register-birth', 'uses' => 'UserController@preRegisterBirthDataPost'));
```

So it recognizes the named route.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Hello, I'm sorry but the problem is that in the post method. the if redirect is not passing the user parameter and makes the get method go always to the else.